# pandas: how to use both name and dataframe of groupby object in an apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas groupby object created by doing

```
g = df.groupby(`id`)
```

on a dataframe `df` that has a column `id`.

Now I also have a function `func` that takes `id, group` as input. I would like to apply `func` to each `id, group` in the groupby object. Currently I use a loop:

```
for id, group in g:
    func(id, group)
```

Is there any better (faster) way of doing this using an apply or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` on the groupby object to apply a function to each group.  Since the function will need to accept the group as its argument, you can use the following:

```
g.apply(lambda grp: f(grp.id.iloc[0], grp))
```

Comment: Thanks, works (after removing the `[0]`). I was surprised to see that it roughly doubles the runtime of the code though.

Comment: Taking a step back, how many rows are there in your pre-grouped dataframe and how many groups are there?  I've found, generally, that a lot of the slick `pandas` features have somewhat high construction overhead, but then wind up being much faster than loops.  So if you had a small number of groups, looping over them and then re-assembling the results might make sense.  But if you had hundreds of groups, I'd expect the `pandas` methods to be more competitive.

Comment: DJ_8one6 - there are 450,000 rows, and 19,000 groups. I would have thought that's large enough to get past the overhead.